# Split from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a CSV file whith this kind of lines:

1,New York city,8175133,40.71455,-74.007124

2,Los Angeles city,3792621,34.05349,-118.245323

I'm doing this method to split it:

```
function processData(csv) {
    var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var lines = [];
    while (allTextLines.length) {
        lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));
    }
    console.log(lines);
    drawOutput(lines);
}
```

But it doesn't work like the way I want. I would like just a part of the string and not teh whole line:

```
lines[0] = New York City, 40.71455, -74.007124

lines[1] = Los Angeles city, 34.05349, -118.245323
```

Is it possible? How Can I split it that way? Already tried a few things, but I didn't find yet a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be something like this:

```
while (allTextLines.length) {
    var line = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
    lines.push([line[1], line[3], line[4]]);
}
```

Since you only want the 2nd, 4th and 5th elements from the original data.

However, you could make it a little easier to access like this:

```
lines.push({city: line[1], lat: line[3], lon: line[4]});
```

This will result in something like:

```
lines[0] === {city: "New York City", lat: 40.71455, lon: -74.007124}
lines[1] === {city: "Los Angeles city", lat: 34.05349, lon: -118.245323}
```

Meaning you can just use: `lines[0].city`.

Or, if you want just those 3 "elements" as a string:

```
lines.push(line[1] + ', ' + line[3] + ', ' + line[4]);
```

Resulting in:

```
lines[0] === "New York City, 40.71455, -74.007124";
lines[1] === "Los Angeles city, 34.05349, -118.245323";
```

Comment: @heisenberg: Excellent, thanks! Did you indeed need the first suggestion I gave, or one of the other 2?

Comment: first one is more then enough because I will never show the data, I will just use it to point the locations in google maps